# Find a path from top-btm with Union Find

Tags: java, data-structures, union-find

## PROBLEMS

1. Is there a path from the top to bottom of a field?
2. Is there still a path if a circular sensor area is added?
3. How many sensors can be added while still having a path?

---

## What I tried

- Created a 2D array
- Used UnionFind Algorithm to find if top-left can make it to bottom-left
- Used trigonometry to create a circular outline of '-1' in 2D array to represent areas that cannot be passed

### Input

- Number of Radars,
- X position of Center, Y position of Center, Radius

### Expected Output

- Number of radars that can be placed while still having a path from top-->btm

#### Code & Examples

Given input:

> 6 36 228 58 164 224 58 88 170 42 93 105 42 167 85 58 28 44 58

Output is 5 - but the expected is 2 (the 3rd radar will block the path from top-->btm

#### What help do I need?

A push in the direction of what I'm doing wrong, or where I need to look to get things right. 
I believe it is something wrong with how the UnionFind creates the Unions, AND/OR testing if there is a path from anywhere in the top, to anywhere in the bottom.

#### Code

Uion Find Code

```
public static class UnionFind {

    // The number of elements in this union find
    private int size;

    // Used to track the size of each of the component
    private int[] sz;

    // id[i] points to the parent of i, if id[i] = i then i is a root node
    private int[] id;

    // Tracks the number of components in the union find
    private int numComponents;

    public UnionFind(int size) {

        if (size <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size <= 0 is not allowed");

        this.size = numComponents = size;
        sz = new int[size];
        id = new int[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            id[i] = i; // Link to itself (self root)
            sz[i] = 1; // Each component is originally of size one
        }
    }

    // Find which component/set 'p' belongs to, takes amortized constant time.
    public int find(int p) {

        // Find the root of the component/set
        int root = p;
        while( root != id[root] )
            root = id[root];

        // Compress the path leading back to the root.
        // Doing this operation is called "path compression"
        // and is what gives us amortized time complexity.
        while(p != root) {
            int next = id[p];
            id[p] = root;
            p = next;
        }

        return root;
    }

    // This is an alternative recursive formulation for the find method
    // public int find(int p) {
    //   if (p == id[p]) return p;
    //   return id[p] = find(id[p]);
    // }

    // Return whether or not the elements 'p' and
    // 'q' are in the same components/set.
    public boolean connected(int p, int q) {
        return find(p) == find(q);
    }

    // Return the size of the components/set 'p' belongs to
    public int componentSize(int p) {
        return sz[find(p)];
    }

    // Return the number of elements in this UnionFind/Disjoint set
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    // Returns the number of remaining components/sets
    public int components() {
        return numComponents;
    }

    // Unify the components/sets containing elements 'p' and 'q'
    public void unify(int p, int q) {

        int root1 = find(p);
        int root2 = find(q);

        // These elements are already in the same group!
        if (root1 == root2) return;

        // Merge smaller component/set into the larger one.
        if (sz[root1] < sz[root2]) {
            sz[root2] += sz[root1];
            id[root1] = root2;
        } else {
            sz[root1] += sz[root2];
            id[root2] = root1;
        }

        // Since the roots found are different we know that the
        // number of components/sets has decreased by one
        numComponents--;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Travel {

    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    public static final int WIDTH = 200;

    private static int getID(int row, int col) {
        return (row*WIDTH) + col;
    }

    private static void drawCircle(int x, int y, int r, int[][] field) {
        double PI = 3.1415926535;
        double i, angle, x1, y1;

        for (i=0; i<360;i++) {
            angle = i;
            x1 = r * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
            y1 = r * sin((angle * PI) / 180);

            int ElX = (int) Math.round(x+x1);
            int ElY = (int) Math.round(y+y1);

            if ((ElX < 0) || (ElX > (WIDTH-1))) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((ElY < 0) || (ElY > (HEIGHT-1))) {
                continue;
            }

            //          System.out.println("The current X:" + x);
            //          System.out.println("The current Y:" + y);
            //
            //          System.out.println("The current ElX: " + ElX);
            //          System.out.println("The current ElY: " + ElY);
            //          System.out.println("");
            field[ElY][ElX] = -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setup initial field
        int[][] field = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

        for (int row=0; row<HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (int col=0; col<WIDTH; col++) {
                field[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }

        //      for (int row=0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        //          for (int col=0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
        //              if (row==0) {
        //                  field[row][col] = 1;
        //              } else if(row==HEIGHT-1) {
        //                  field[row][col] = 0;
        //              } else {
        //                  field[row][col] = WIDTH*row+col;
        //              }
        //          }
        //      }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfSensors = in.nextInt();
        int numOfSensorsOnField = 0;
        UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(HEIGHT*WIDTH);

        for(int i=0; i<numOfSensors; i++) {
            int x = in.nextInt();
            int y = in.nextInt();
            int r = in.nextInt();

            //field[y][x] = -1;
            drawCircle(x, y, r, field);
            numOfSensorsOnField++;

            for (int row=0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < WIDTH; col++) {
                    if ((row < (HEIGHT-1)) && (field[row][col]==field[row+1][col])) {
                        uf.unify(getID(row,col), getID(row+1, col));
                    }
                    if ((col < (WIDTH -1)) && (field[row][col]==field[row][col+1])) {
                        uf.unify(getID(row,col), getID(row, col+1));
                    }
                }
            }

            boolean bottom = false;
            //          for (int col=0; col<WIDTH; col++) {
            //              for (int colBtm=col; col<WIDTH; col++) {
            //                  if(uf.find(getID(0,col)) == uf.find(getID(HEIGHT-1, colBtm))) {
            //                      bottom = true;
            //                  }   
            //              }
            //          }
            if(uf.find(getID(0,0)) == uf.find(getID(HEIGHT-1,WIDTH-1))){
                System.out.println(uf.find(getID(0,0)));
                bottom = true;
            }
            System.out.println("Boolean is: " + bottom);
            if (!bottom) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //in.nextInt();

        //      for (int row=0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        //          for (int col=0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
        //              System.out.print(field[row][col]);
        //              System.out.print("\t");
        //          }
        //          System.out.println();
        //      }

        System.out.println(numOfSensorsOnField-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note the paragraph "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". Is your basic question how do I find if a line intersects with a circle ?

Comment: I have taken the tour, and reviewed the "how do I ask a good question". Is this better?

Comment: To me it is still far to long and not clear. Are you looking for a straight line  path from top left to bottom right ? When you write sensor or radar, do you mean obstacles ?

Comment: Side note : no need for ` double PI = 3.1415926535;` use `Math.PI` (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI))

Comment: It doesn't have to be a straight line path, it only has to be a path. "Sensor or radar" are what I used to understand the problem. They could be considered unpassable obstacles as well.

Comment: My tip is to ask a question in the best way to represent a (one) problem. It does not need to represent your specific use-case or your application. When I see terms like "sensor" or "radar" I need to assume or guess what they mean. Obstacle in a path seems to me much clearer. The same applies for "union find". It is not clear what that means.